# Download a linked swf file?

Tags: flash, alien-juice-bar

I am trying to download the full game [Alien Juice Bar](https://static.lawrencehallofscience.org/scienceview/scienceview.berkeley.edu/html/showcase/flash/juicebar.html)

When I download the swf file, I can only see the main screen the buttons will not work to take me to the rest of the game.

I am assuming there are more swf files that this links to but I cannot find them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because downloading swf files is not specific to gaming. I suggest you ask this over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Voting to leave open. The questions seems to me to be about the precise way Alien Juice Bar references other SWF files, not about how to download them in general.

Answer (score 1):

GEMS Alien Juice Bar is playable offline through [Flashpoint Archive](https://flashpointarchive.org/). Simply install Flashpoint Infinity and search for "Alien Juice Bar".

[image: Playing Alien Juice Bar]